Sci-fi/fantasy book set on an alien planet where the young protagonist and their friend try to break out of their walled-in town
I'm trying to find a sci-fi/fantasy book that I read in the mid-to-late 2000s. The book was hardcover and missing its jacket, so I don't know what the cover looks like but it was a blue hard cover. The title might have started with an 'f' but I may be imagining things.
The plot involved a young protagonist and friend (both human/alien crosses; think Avatar but small and more animal-adjacent) discovering something in the city/town they're living in. The town is on an alien planet and is in a fairly dense forested area. The leadership of this town was secretive and corrupt and they had a protective wall around the town that no one could go in or out of. I think it was said to keep beasts out or something but the protagonist suspected that it was to keep the people in. They broke out or tried to break out, I don't really remember.
I don't think the book was too old but it was in my elementary school's library. I would love to find it and give it another read because I think about it all the time. Thanks.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Knife_of_Never_Letting_Go
